# How does one import a child component in react?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

The component which is external includes and external file

```
  class NavigationBarContainer extends React.PureComponent {
 render = () => <NavigationBar extraBanner={<Banner 
   />} {...this.props} />
```

}

in my App

```
   import NavigationBar from '../components/NavigationBar'

    <NavigationBar
      extraBanner />
```

doesn't seem to work

```
  import NavigationBarContainer from '../components/NavigationBar'
     <NavigationBarContainer {...this.props}>
```

doesnt seem to work either getting error below

```
**Invalid prop extraBanner of type boolean supplied to NavigationBar, expected a single ReactElement.**
```

Comment: You are not exporting your Class in the first file

"export class NavigationBarContainer"

Comment: extraBanner props nothing returns in your code , whta's the purpose of that props ? or explain a bit more to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible things that are wrong here.

1) `NavigationBarContainer` is not being exported, thus you cannot import it.

You can fix this by making sure to export the class one of two ways -- either change the class declaration to include the `export` keyword

```
export default class NavigationBarContainer extends React.PureComponent
```

or add a line to the bottom of that file

```
export default NavigationBarContainer;
```

2) You are trying to import a component called `NavigationBarContainer` from a file called `NavigationBar`. If that file is called `NavigationBarContainer` then this will not work. Make sure that your file names are correct.

---

A quick summary of `export` vs `export default` and importing

`export default`

The default export can be given any name when imported, eg.

```
// components/MyComponent.js
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {...}

// AnotherFile.js
import MyComponent from 'components/MyComponent'; // works
import WhateverName from 'components/MyComponent'; // also works
```

`export`

When you don't use the `default` keyword, then you're making a named export. These have to be imported directly by name, using this syntax:

```
// components/SmallComponents.js
export class SmallComponent1 extends React.Component {...}
export class SmallComponent2 extends React.Component {...}

// AnotherFile.js
import {SmallComponent1, SmallComponent2} from 'components/SmallComponents'; // works
import SmallComponent1 from 'components/SmallComponents' // does not work
import {WhateverName} from 'components/SmallComponents' // does not work
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: actually i do have the export- added to the question